# Programmatically disable a reactive form component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I understand how we can specify the initial state of a reactive form control to be disabled.

`someControl: [{value: '', disabled: true}]`

How can I change the disable state at a later time, programmatically, based on a selection of another value in the form. So, e.g. `someControl` should be disabled if `anotherControl` has a certain value selected in a dropdown and enabled otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should work

```
this.someControl.reset({value: '', disabled: true});
```

Comment: Is There are reason , this answer was down voted? Please share if have a valid reason . I will try to improve the answer in future.

Answer (score 17):

You can watch for `valueChanges` with your select field, here's an example with a form with a dropdown and an input field that we will disable/enable based on value chosen from dropdown:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  selects: [''],
  inputField: ['']
})

  // subscribe to changes in select field, if the value chosen is "two", 
  // disable input field, else enable field
  this.myForm.get('selects').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    if(val === 'two') {
      this.myForm.get('inputField').disable()
    }
    else {
      this.myForm.get('inputField').enable()
    }
  })
```

Here's a

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gJAFxFf6GswTMF3M7yLv?p=preview)

---

### EDIT:

As developer033 suggested, you can also use simple change event, where template...

```
<select formControlName="selects" (change)="checkValue()">
  <option disabled></option>
  <option *ngFor="let a of arr">{{a}}</option>
</select>
```

and component would be:

```ts
checkValue() {
  if(this.myForm.get('selects').value === 'two') {
    this.myForm.get('inputField').disable()
  }
  else {
    this.myForm.get('inputField').enable()
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :) But, instead of subscribing to the `valueChanges`, I'd prefer to use `(change)` *event* on `select`.

Comment: :) Yeah, I figured first that I would do it with change event, but thought that since we are dealing with a model-driven form, leeeet's go with valueChanges, but yes, you are absolutely right, might even just be wiser to use change event ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This answer definitely provides more details. I think both answers are helpful. I will upvote this one.

Comment: No problem, you decide what answer to accept :) Have a good one and happy coding! :)